# How can I make my question clearer?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

A few days ago I [asked this question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/4g-router-for-home-use).

It hasn't received much attention other than a few upvotes (*with a single downvote the same time as the downvoted answer was upvoted*), and the OP of the answer doesn't seem to grasp that their suggestion does not meet one of the requirements that I set out in the question:

> Should be suited to home networking (don't want a portable router)

I then started suspecting that the question *could* have quality issues (namely, clarity of the question), and one of the comments by the OP suggests this:

> But isn't that EXACTLY what this does? " It's made to be used as a wifi router " Unless wifi router means something different to you, i do not see why this one would not solve your issue? I never move my wifi router, it stays in it's place and cover the whole house. this one is just that. it's meant to be used like that. YOu should be a little more clearer on what is wrong with this one, or what is exactly that you're looking for and is lacking in this one. It'l help me help you

Are there quality issues with my question, and if so, how can I make the question better?

It seems that from the OP of the answer's point of view, that I haven't made it clear that I do not want a portable router (MiFi). I've added another bullet point to try and make this clearer:

> **Not portable**- Portable 'MiFi' routers often have a very low WiFi signal range. This device will be used in a home, in place of a standard WiFi broadband router.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, your question is good as it is now. It makes clear what you want - and what you don't want - and specifies it nicely. I don't think there's any action necessary on your part to clear the question up. The fact that it's not getting answers isn't necessarily indicative of problems, either - being a *specific recommendations* site, we have a higher percentage of unanswered questions.

The fact that the answer doesn't answer your question is through no fault of your own, and I'm going to go and review it as soon as I've pressed the button to post this answer.